# Objectify Query a attribute from an entity

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Is there a possible way to query a particular attribute from an entity using Objectify,

Lets say i have an  **Class entity with attributes {id,name,mail}**,how to **filter only the mail attribute**  from the entity ? previously  I was fetching the entire entity

```
Objectify ofy=ObjectifyService.begin();
Query<entity> q=ofy.query(entity.class);
```

and then retrieving the value q.getmail();

I am looking for filtering only ****mail attribute from entity*** * in the query q ? please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how objectify works. You load the entire entity as a bean with a query. There's not really a synonym for SQL "select mail from entity where id=?" in objectify. What you can do is control which associated entities in the graphy are loaded from the datastore when you do a fetch (in objectify 4) using LoadGroups (https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BasicOperations#Load_Groups) but I don't think that's what you are asking.

That said, fetching 1 field and fetching an entire object take basically the same amount of time in appengine.