# Objectify Projection Query with Filters

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Given the class

```
@Entity
public class Goat{
   Long pen;
   Long car;
   Boolean active;
   …
}
```

I need to create a projection query that returns a list of `Long`s. How should I edit the following so it works?

```
List<Long> cars = ofy().load().type(Goat.class).filter("pen", pen).filter("active", true).project("car").list();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index all fields you plan to query/filter on.
eg.

```
@Index
 Long pen;
@Index
 Long car;
```

Comment: It does not compile. Is it acceptable to change to `type(Long.class)`? How does it know which class I am querying? On the other hand if I don't specify Long it does not agree with the expected type.

Comment: what does not compile?

Comment: Since I am expecting `List<Long>` if I set the type as `type(Goat.class)` it does not compile. So it seems to expect both the type being queried and the result set to have the same type. Basically read my line of code to see my mismatch. Or I guess the projection still returns `Goat` but with only `car` defined.

Comment: AS stated on this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862936/querying-selected-fields-in-an-entity-in-objectify-appengine the project does not work as a SQL select statement, you still get the whole entity.

Comment: Furthermore, projection queries are fairly exotic and should not be used by beginners on GAE. Consider them an optimization that you should use as a last resort when you really know what you're doing.